Linux 5.15.0-122 won't get to login screen with nvidia drivers but -119 does boot
I am having an issue that none of the forum posts have helped me resolve. I have a Thinkpad P1 Gen 5 with an A2000 graphics card (Ubuntu 20.04 due to need to run ROS1) that I'm currently using Nvidia 535 drivers with. I am stuck in a loop where I can get to the login screen on the -119 Linux kernel version from Grub but not the -122 kernel where I get the flashing line and can access a prompt via ALT + F3. I have tried the following:

Ubuntu 20.04 boots to black screen with flashing cursor by setting GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset".
Booted into -122 kernel, removed Nvidia drivers and attempted to reboot (failed) using sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-535

Attempted to install Nvidia Drivers when in prompt on -122 (failed)



Any help would be appreciated as I'm definitely beyond my skills right now in trying to fix this. This started when I was following the instructions to install QTile with the following commands:
sudo apt install xserver-xorg xinit
sudo apt install libpangocairo-1.0-0
sudo apt install python3-pip python3-xcffib python3-cairocffi

pip install qtile

Nvidia Drivers
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-535:amd64                    535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-535                        535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                 535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:i386                  535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-535:amd64                  535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-535:i386                   535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-535:amd64                  535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-535:i386                   535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-535:amd64                   535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:amd64                    535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386                     535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:amd64                      535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:i386                       535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-535-5.15.0-122-generic 5.15.0-122.132~20.04.1                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-122
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-20.04  5.15.0-122.132~20.04.1                amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-535 for the generic-hwe-20.04 flavour
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-5.15.0-122-generic 5.15.0-122.132~20.04.1                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-122 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-122-generic  5.15.0-122.132~20.04.1                amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-122-generic
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-535                    535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-535                             535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-535                           535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-firmware-535-535.183.01              535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-535                    535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-535                    535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.16~0.20.04.2                      all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                             470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.3            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-535                            535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                     0.18build1                            all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535               535.183.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

